# Find file by size is not working?

Tags: find

I have a file with size 6284,

```
# ll 1.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6284 Jan 10 19:02 1.jpg
```

When I do `find . -size 6284` or `find . -size 6284b`, it shows nothing. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to `man find`, using the `b` suffix to a `-size` constraint imposes units of 512-byte blocks.

To use units of byte, use the suffix `c`:

```
# find . -size 6284c
./1.jpg
```